# Gremlin Visualization Options: Size of Node

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

This is a query about the size of the nodes in the visualization output of a Gremlin notebook. I want to be able to specify the size of certain nodes with the same label or property so that they stand out in comparison to other nodes.

Following through the examples provided by [link](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/blob/main/src/graph_notebook/notebooks/02-Visualization/Grouping-and-Appearance-Customization-Gremlin.ipynb), I've implemented the size option for nodes that have specific labels. The result seems to be that the node increases in size once you click on it in the visual. Is there a way to have the node size persist so that all nodes with a specific label or property are always larger than other nodes in the visual?

Example code from the above link:

```
%%graph_notebook_vis_options
{
  "groups": {
      "['CA']": {"color": "red", "size": 3},
    "['MX']": {"shape": "image", 
               "image":"https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/mexico/flag-round-250.png"
              , "size": 50},
    
    "['US']": {
      "shape": "icon",
      "icon": {
        "face": "FontAwesome",
        "code": "\uf072",
        "color": "#00FF00"
          }, "size": 37
      }
    }
}
```

```
%%gremlin -p v,inv -g country
g.V().hasLabel('airport').has('code','CZM').out('route').path().by(valueMap())
```

Comment: This is a feature request that is being tracked by a few Git issues. The original issue being this one.  https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/issues/28. I would recommend doing a +1 on that issue and also copying the example of what you tried to it.